# Mounted Drive Appears to Ignore fstab Using Disk Utility

Tags: centos, mount, fstab

I have an external USB drive with the label `Backup 1`.

I wish to mount it at the mount point `/backup1`.

To do this, I have the following entry in my `fstab`:

```
LABEL=Backup\0401   /backup1        ext4        defaults        0 0
```

(the `\040` matches the space in the label name.

No this works perfectly for another drive with the label `Backup 2`, so I know that there’s nothing wrong with the entry.

If I mount the drive using

```
mount /backup1
```

It works.

However, if I mount the drive using the Gnome Disk Utility, it appears to ignore the `fstab` entry, and mount it in `/media/Backup 1`.

This is not the case for other drives mounted this way.

What would cause the mount process to ignore the `fstab` entry and mount it there?

I might add that in the past I had used the drive before with the label `DVD`. Obviously it has the same UUID, so I wondered whether there is an entry in some other file which is responsible for this.

I am using CENTOS 6.

Comment: I believe Nautilus controls the automounting. This link https://askubuntu.com/questions/18926/how-to-control-gnomes-auto-mounting-capabilities seems to have several solutions, though it sounds like it's an all or nothing thing: if you turn off automounting, you lose it for all external drives.

Comment: Gnome Disk Utility is a front-end to the `udisks` subsystem. You might want to run `udisks --show-info /dev/<disk device>` for both your backup disks and see what might make the difference between your Backup 1 and Backup 2.